# How to compare a dataframe with a list and remove all rows which contain values from the list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column `Lien` with a string for each `row` and a list of string.

```
Date de publication   Lien   Titre
0   24/05/2021   string   string
1   21/05/2021   string   string
2   21/05/2021   string   string
3   21/05/2021   string   string
4   21/05/2021   string   string
```

I want to compare the column `Lien` with the list and create a new dataframe or edit the initial one with all rows which contain values from the list removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have this dataframe:

```
  Date de publication     Lien   Titre
0          24/05/2021  string1  string
1          21/05/2021  string2  string
2          21/05/2021  string3  string
3          21/05/2021  string4  string
4          21/05/2021  string5  string
```

Then you can filter this dataframe by list using `.isin()`. For example:

```py
to_remove = ["string2", "string4"]

print(df[~df["Lien"].isin(to_remove)])
```

Prints:

```
  Date de publication     Lien   Titre
0          24/05/2021  string1  string
2          21/05/2021  string3  string
4          21/05/2021  string5  string
```